# You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual

Tags: mysql, syntax

MySQL query:

```
set @row_num = 0; SELECT profile, row_number as rank FROM(SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number, time, profile, map FROM records WHERE map='". $map ."' ORDER BY time) as t WHERE profile='". $profile ."'
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT profile, row_number as rank FROM(SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_nu' at line 1

Comment: Are you using PHP? You can only have one query in a single `mysql_query()`, here you have two (the `set @row_num = 0` is a query, the select also)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to execute 2 statements in one step. Use

```
SELECT profile, row_number as rank 
FROM
(
  SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number, time, profile, map 
  FROM records, (select @row_num := 0) r
  WHERE map='". $map ."' 
  ORDER BY time
) as t
WHERE profile='". $profile ."'
```

to combine that into one.